# Could you magnetize and at the same time elactrostatically charge a piece of rusted iron?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, material-science, metamaterials

Pure iron rust (i.e. iron oxide) can be electrostatically charged and also magnetized.

In a piece of iron usually the surface starts rusting leaving the interior untouched.

Is it possible to have such a piece of rusted in the surface only, iron and exposing it accordingly to an external static or magnetic source to make it both to be magnetized as well as electrostatic charged at the same time?

And if not, what about pure rust, iron oxide, can this be simultaneously electrostatically charged and also magnetized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we say "a piece of iron" it usualy ment a piece of steel. Pure iron is very uncommon. Many varieties of steel can be magnetized (they are feromagnetic). The rust on the surface does not change this. Rust is not a simple iron oxide but it may contain hydrated forms of oxides and hidroxides. Some oxides are ferrimagnetic so they can be magnetized ($Fe_2O_3$). Others are paramagnetic so they cannot retain permanent magnetization. So, "pure iron rust" does not designate a real thing and rust's magnetic properties depends a lot of the composition of the rust. This does not matter much for magnetization of a rusty piece of steel but it is imprtant for the magnetization of rust itself.
For electrostatic charging, it does not matter much. Both insulating and conductive materials can retain electrostatic charges for the right conditions. But for conductive materials is tricky, you need to ensure proper insulation. The rust does not produce a good electrical insulation for electrostatic purposes.